# The class XXX was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

In production I've got this error :
`The class 'Generic\UserBundle\Entity\Session' was not found in the chain configured namespaces`

When checking my entities with `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info` this is what I get

### dev:

```
Found 18 mapped entities:

[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ArticleOpen
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleQuote
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Comment
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleVideo
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleGallery
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ArticlesUsers
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleText
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Story
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleTitle
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleGalleryPicture
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModulePicture
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Category
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Group
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Article
[OK]   Generic\UserBundle\Entity\Session
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
```

### prod

```
Found 17 mapped entities:
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModulePicture
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Group
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ArticlesUsers
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Story
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleTitle
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Category
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ArticleOpen
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleQuote
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Article
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleGalleryPicture
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\Comment
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleGallery
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleVideo
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\ModuleText
[OK]   App\AdminBundle\Entity\User
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
[OK]   FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group
```

As you can see the entity `Generic\UserBundle\Entity\Session` is missing in production. Ive checked the bundle is registered in appKernel and not under the 'dev' section. I've also check the path for typo having case sensitive content in some files/folder but everything seems fine.

Another fact worth mentioning is, I've manually copied this bundle from another project I didn't used the console to generate it so I might have forgot something. The missing entity is the only one on that bundle so it is possible that the whole bundle is wrong not just this entity (but at the same time how can it work in dev mode ?)

Thank you

Comment: @Jan.J, the command returned ```Generating autoload files``` but nothing changed

Comment: long shot, but manually dump the prod cache and then run `php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: @MattHB that made me find an error in my session class but now I've corrected it, it says ```Warming up the cache for the prod environment with debug false```with no errors but my entity is still missing

Comment: Try to see if the Session class is actually located under srs/Generic/UserBundle/Entity/Session.php
If not, move it there... or change the namespace. To App\AdminBundle\Entity\Session

Comment: @Koalabaerchen the file is on the right place and the namespace on it is good too, it would work on dev env otherwise. Also as mentioned in the question, I've check that the path doesn't have a typo because my production server is Case Sensitive.